# Изображение в качестве фона экрана активности

Tags: java, android

У меня возникла некоторая проблема со SplashScreen. Я хотел заменить фон этого загрузочного экрана. Но моя картинка несколько растянута получилось. А какую же тогда по размеру ее мне нужно сделать? И как быть с размером, например, значка приложения, логотипом приложения (тоже на экран, например, авторизации добавлю). Как эти размеры можно получить?

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Андроид работает на устройствах с разным разрешением экрана и плотностью пикселей (да, я открыл Америку). 
На данный момент Android поддерживает следующие параметры плотности пикселей: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.

Базовой является плотность mdpi, когда 1px = 1dp. Остальные являются множителями:

```
LDPI: Portrait: 200 X 320px
MDPI: Portrait: 320 X 480px
HDPI: Portrait: 480 X 800px
XHDPI: Portrait: 720 X 1280px
XXHDPI: Portrait: 960 X 1600px
XXXHDPI: Portrait: 1440 x 2560px
```

Вы должны создать несколько копий вашего изображения под разные экраны и положить их в папки drawable с нужным идентификатром (drawable-hdpi и т.д.) Система сама выберет нужное в зависимости от экрана устройства.
Возможно придётся задать дополнительные параметры для layout'а, в котором будет лежать картинка:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:scaleType = "centerCrop" // вид масштабирования
```

Насчёт значка приложения, андроид-студия имеет встроенные средства для генерации значков (Image Asset), вы можете создать его на основе вашей картинки. Можно использовать сторонние генераторы, например [этот](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=0&foreground.space.pad=0.15&foreColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)&crop=1&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher).
Такой сгенерированный значок можно будет использовать на экране активности, и он будет адаптирован под разные расширения.

И вообще-то использовать картинки на весь экран нежелательно))

Также имейте ввиду, что изображения слишком большого размера будут плохо влиять на производительность.

Подробнее [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/design/basic.php).

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, что смог только сейчас увидеть этот пост. Хотел бы уточнить. Мне нужно брать основные разрешения экранов и под них рассчитывать размер изображения той самой формулой? Т.е. для одного разрешения получится 6 файлов разных размеров? И файлы все будут одинаково называться?

Comment: @odosenok Нет. Одна картинка на одно разрешение. Просто создать картинки нужных размеров и положить их в нужные папки drawable. Андроид Студия перед тем как вставить картинку в проект спросит, в какую подпапку её положить, там увидите нужный идентификатор типа HDPI и др.

Comment: @YoungBlade, хорошо, пойду с другой стороны. Я беру картинку под разрешение 1080x1920. Соответственно, ее размер тоже 1080x1920. Далее тыкаю на "Image Asset" (в mipmap). Она автоматически вставляется в разных размерах под разные плотности пикселей (hdpi, mdpi, xdhpi, ...). Для разрешения 320х426 нужно просто обрезать имеющуюся и добавить ее заново через Image Asset?

Comment: @odosenok нет. в  mipmap лежат иконки приложения, иконка не может быть такой большой. та таблица размеров предназначена для фоновых изображений

Comment: @YoungBlade, я имею в виду как раз таки фоновое изображение. В SplashScreen хочу на весь экран логотип засунуть. А вопрос в том, каким размером делать этот логотип фотошоперу (я не фотошопер)... Потому и спрашиваю здесь как быть. Да и в будущем, если и не в стиле использовать, как правильно быть с размерами...

Comment: @odosenok помоему вы отделяете понятие плотности пикселей от разрешения. разрешению 320 X 480px соответствует плотность пикселей MDPI. вы вставляете картинку такого размера в папку drawable с идентификатором mdpi, далее вставляете картинку разрешением 480 X 800px в hdpi

Comment: @YoungBlade, да, вы правы, я не так понял изначально) Спасибо большое :)